# Run sql-lint on more than one file

Tags: sql, static-analysis, lint

Is there a way to run sql-lint on a bunch of files? All examples show how to run sql-lint on one file only (sql-lint -f ).
Thanks!

Comment: Depending on your operating system, make a `.bat` script file (windows) or `.sh` script file (*nix)

Comment: :-) I wanted to ignore the script. I thought the sql-lint command can get a flag (option) to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Author of sql-lint here. There's some upcoming work to make it recurse down and lint every SQL file. In the meantime you can use this:

```
find . -iname "*.sql" | xargs -L1 sql-lint -f
```

Hope that helps!